# How to set Left, Center and Right headphone as Default iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios7, avcapturesession, audiobuffer, audio-comparison

I am using **AudioComponentInstance** for listing audio from Mice and play it in headphone directly. Now, I have to **play audio** if **left, right or center** as we have in default iPhone settings.

[image]

As there is a property called **“pan”** in **AVAudioPlayer** to set volume for left, center and right. Capture sound is played in headphone using **AudioBuffer**. I have to do some calculation and modification in it.  I did research on it. But not getting anything. Is there any way that I can do the same thing in **AudioComponentInstance**?